# Python-based toolbox for generating 3D solid mesh based on implicit function

Tags: python, mesh, modeling

I am looking for an open-source toolbox or a python library that can generate 3D solid mesh based on implicit functions (i.e. F(x,y,z) < 0). For solid mesh, I mean, for example, tetrahedron or cube or any types of polyhedra.

The marching cubes algorithm that I am using can only generate surface mesh according to the given implicit function (i.e. F(x,y,z)=0).

If there is no existing open-source toolbox or library, I would like to know what algorithms can be used to achieve this goal.

Thank you!!

Comment: https://github.com/daavoo/pyntcloud

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@HSChan. Have a look at [PyMesh](https://pymesh.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: Thank you very much for the helpful information. I found it can perform tetrahedralization which generates 3D tetrahedral mesh according to 2D surface mesh. https://pymesh.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_mesh_generation.html